# Google Maps markers show same info

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I know that similar questions have been asked before but the provided answers don't solve my problem. I have a loop in which I iterate through places, create markers and add eventlisteners. When I click on any of the markers afterwards they all show the same information.

```
  var geocoder;
 var map;
function initialize() {

// Load places from xml file
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","person_city_clause.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

var text =
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("text");

var places = [];
var descriptions = [];

for (var i=3; i<text.length; i++)
{
    places.push(text[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue); // place
    descriptions[places[i]] = descriptions.push(text[i-2].childNodes[0].nodeValue); // person
    i=i+3;
}

// Create inital Google Map
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);



// fill map with place markers
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker = [];

for (var i=0; i<places.length; i++)
{
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': places[i]}, function(results, status) 
    {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
        {
            marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location});

            listenMarker(marker[i], results[0].formatted_address );
        }

    })  
}

function listenMarker(marker, place)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.setContent("" + place);
            infowindow.open(map, this);});
            }
```

}

edit: when I do alert(i) after geocoder.geocode I always get 32 (the size of the places array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an array for the infowindows aswell, if you do not do this the infowindow variable gets overridden by the next marker..

The content is the same for all of them..

EDIT: Just make another global array:

```
    var locations = [];

    ..code blabla
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k<results.length;k++{
            locations.push = results[k].geometry.location;
        }
    }
```

You can loop through this array using this:

```
for(int i=0; i<locations.length;i++)
{

}
```

Comment: This only gives me more infowindows, but doesn't solve the problem of displaying the same content. Apparently that has something to do with the callback function but I have no experience with this.

Comment: Hmm so if you use infoWindows[i].setContent("" + i) it doesnt work properly?

I've had problems with infoWindows before, back then i couldn't find out the proper way to initialise them myself.. Ended up throwing the whole infowindows thingy away and creating thesame effect outside the map with label and textbox controls :D

Comment: all the questions on this I can find deal with this problem when geolocations are already stored in an array. As soon as I try to do the whole thing _within_ the geocoding thing it doesn't work. I have tried putting the creation of markers and infowindows outside the geocoding, but I can't get that to work either. How would I go from an array of locations to an array of coordinates? That would solve my problem too!!

Comment: sorry, I meant as in geocoding an array of locations (strings) into an array of coordinates.

Comment: Np, try my new version, made some silly mistake.. Instead of passing the location i passed the entire geothingy..

Comment: hey rob, thats not working either I can add stuff to the array, but my code to place the markers (which is below your code snippet) is reached too soon.

Comment: Sounds like that status.OK isn't working properly, you sure you shouldn't use something like status.Finished??

Comment: nope, status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK should work but it indeed seems like it doesn;t

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a local var in the context of the function, that creates the event function:

```
...

var index = i;

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

  ...

  infowindow.setContent("" + index);
```